# Remove pre-installed configuration on Android phone

Tags: applications, root-access, nexus-4, installation

I have an Android phone which constantly tells me to install a specific app from Google Play. It's just a configuration which is pre-installed on my phone but I cannot figure out how to remove this configuration.

I now run Android 5.0 and it's a Nexus 4.

Comment: what app is it trying to make you install?

Answer (score 0):

Long press the notification and it will show you what app sent the notification. Next, go to Settings > Apps and look for the app. Once you click it you will have the option to disable notifications, or to diable the whole app.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have disabled notifications from Core Services but I guess Core Services does other things except from notifying me to download this annoying app. How can the vendor install such things on my phone without letting me deleting it?